# Auto Generate Documentation for ASP.net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I currently have a MVC project in ASP.Net that is using a WebApi. Most of the code for the controllers is written in c#. I'd like to automatically generate a description of API calls including:

> 1.)    The url of the page/endpoint
>
> 2.)    Description of what endpoint/page does
>
> 3.)    List of arguments with descriptions and datatypes.
>
> 4.)    HTTP Verb (get, post, put, delete)
>
> 5.)    The permissions required for the page

The description will have to be written manually.

I've read quite a few other articles that result in the individual using a 3rd party application like Swagger. Is there something built in to ASP.Net to help with this? If I wanted to try to generate documentation myself (without using 3rd party software), how would I get started on creating such documentation?

I've spent a fair amount of time googling various queries and can't seem to find an answer.

Edit: What's the benefit of using Swagger over ASP.Net help pages in my case?

Comment: Something like this?  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

Comment: That looks like it could be what I was looking for. I'll take a look at it, then get back. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Swagger is even used by Azure API Apps, so you should probably prefer it. You can use [Swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/5.2.0) to generate the documentation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What's the benefit of using Swagger over ASP.Net in my case?

Comment: If your swagger api consumer is something like SwaggerUI, it would allow users to try out the api calls right from the documentation

Comment: @Speerian You aren't using one over the other - Swagger has become the standard for ASP.NET as well. The reason is that Swagger is *not* only human-readable documentation, but can be used as an API's schema as well. Azure API apps expose Swagger so that the underlying service knows what are the endpoints, DTOs, who is permitted to use what and how to bill them

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As an alternative to Swagger you can make use of the ['Help Pages'](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) for ASP.NET Web API.

Entries within this documentation are generated automatically and will contain information such as:

- Relative URI
- HTTP Method
- Sample Request/Response data
- A description of the API purpose (derived from XML comments)

If using a third party component ***is*** possible then I would recommend you use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) (Use the [Swashbuckle NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/)) to achieve API documentation.

Comment: The downside of using Help Pages is that it adds _a ton_ of stuff to your project. The downside of Swagger/Swashbuckle is that [it doesn't support multiple Web API actions at the same URL path but with different parameters](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/142).

Answer (score 5):

Swagger does not just list your api uris. Users actually try them out and see the response

Swagger has tools to create the documentation before you implement it.

It can also add description using the comments.